# Unlisting a list of list while keeping second list names

Tags: r, list

I would like to unlist a list of list while keeping the names of the second list.

For example if have a list like this:

```
$`listA`  
  $`listA_a`
    [1] 1 2
  $`listA_g`
    [1] 1 2    
$`listB`  
  $`listB_b`
    [1] 1 2
```

I would like to obtain this list:

```
$`listA_a`
  [1] 1 2
$`listA_g`
  [1] 1 2    
$`listB_b`
  [1] 1 2
```

I know there is an argument in unlist to keep names (use.names = T, which is true by default)
however it keeps the names of the first list and add a number if there is several elements ("listA1", "listA2", "listB").

(This is an example but in my code the elements of the list are plots so I cannot use a data.frame or anything... I cannot easily reconstruct the names as they contain informations about the data used for the plots).

Thank you very much for your help!

Pernille

Comment: Using the `purrr` package you could do `purrr::flatten(List)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this approach. You can use `unlist()` with `recursive=F` to keep the desired structure and then format the names. Here the code:

```
#Data
List <- list(listA = list(listA_a = c(1, 2), listA_g = c(1, 2)), listB = list(
  listB_b = c(1, 2)))
#Code
L <- unlist(List,recursive = F)
names(L) <- gsub(".*\\.","", names(L) )
L
```

Output:

```
L
$listA_a
[1] 1 2

$listA_g
[1] 1 2

$listB_b
[1] 1 2
```

Or the more simplified version without regex (Many thanks and credits to **@markus**):

```
#Code 2
L <- unlist(unname(List),recursive = F)
```

Output:

```
L
$listA_a
[1] 1 2

$listA_g
[1] 1 2

$listB_b
[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `rrapply` from `rrapply`

```
library(rrapply)
rrapply(List, how = 'flatten')
#$listA_a
#[1] 1 2

#$listA_g
#[1] 1 2

#$listB_b
#[1] 1 2
```

#### data

```
List <- list(listA = list(listA_a = c(1, 2), listA_g = c(1, 2)), listB = list(
  listB_b = c(1, 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to make use of e.g. `Reduce` to concatenate the sublists:

```
list_of_lists <- list(
  listA = list(listA_a = c(1, 2), listA_g = c(1, 2)), 
  listB = list(listB_b = c(1, 2)
))
Reduce(c, list_of_lists)
#> $listA_a
#> [1] 1 2
#> 
#> $listA_g
#> [1] 1 2
#> 
#> $listB_b
#> [1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `flatten` from package `purrr`

```
> purrr::flatten(lst)
$listA_a
[1] 1 2

$listA_g
[1] 1 2

$listB_b
[1] 1 2
```